# Bipartite Graph.

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Scientists have identified 20 traits for humans.
Each person has 8 of these 20 traits before birth. In addition, human beings are unique and no one set of traits is the same.
Show that a human being may acquire a new trait during his or her lifetime so that the human being remains unique.

Comment: Please note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). It would be helpful, for instance, if you could answer any of the following questions. Where did you encounter this problem? What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just know that we need to define a two-part graph, one part of which is human and the other part of which is a subset of nine members of the traits.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "a human being may acquire a new trait during his or her lifetime so that the human being remains unique"? Does that mean that all humans acquire an additional trait and we're meant to show that this can be done in such a way that the resulting "altered" humans are unique? Or, is it just one human being that acquires a new trait? Does this trait replace another or is it added to the set?

Comment: A human can find a new trait so that human beings always remain unique.

Comment: Your comment does not resolve the ambiguity that I asked about

Comment: "all humans acquire an additional trait and we're meant to show that this can be done in such a way that the resulting "altered" humans are unique". Its true

Comment: Perfect, thank you

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For simplicity of argument, let's suppose that every possible set of $8$ traits corresponds to one of the humans so that there are the maximal number $\binom {20}{8}$ humans; if there aren't enough humans, then it is only easier to ensure that the humans remain unique after gaining a trait.

For each set $A$ of $8$ traits and $B$ of $9$ traits, connect $A$ to $B$ if and only if $A \subset B$. Each such set $A$ is connected to $20 - 8 = 12$ sets. A pair of distinct sets $A_1,A_2$ connect to a common set $B$ of $9$ traits if and only if $|A_1 \setminus A_2| = 1$, and in this case they both connect to $B = A_1 \cup A_2$.

---

Using [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3969189/81360): verify that the degree of each subset with size $8$ (each "human") has degree $20 - 8 = 12$, while each subset of size $9$ has degree $9$. The conclusion follows from the fact that $12 \geq 9$.

Comment: I don't understand this (or am perhaps visualizing the setup differently) - why doesn't a given $B$ connect to $9$ different $A$ sets, one for each missed trait?

Comment: @Ben Grossmann thank you but our teacher told us to give one part of which is human and the other part of which is a subset of nine members of the traits. help me

Comment: @Joffan You're right

Comment: @Elliot That's basically what I have done. Whether you call the first part "humans" or "subsets of size $8$" is irrelevant mathematically.

Comment: Probably should also note that $\binom {20}{9} > \binom {20}{8} $

Comment: @Ben Grossmann thanks, do you know this question? => https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3969189/868885

Comment: @Elliot Actually, with that result we can quickly answer this question

Comment: thanks for attention.ᗢ